# C++: Dynamically growing 2d array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, double, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following situation solved with a `vector`, but one of my older colleagues told me in a discussion that it would be much faster with an array.

I calculate lots (and I mean lots!) of 12-dimensional vectors from lots of audio files and have to store them for processing. I really need all those vectors before I can start my calculation. Anyhow, I can not predict how many audios, and I can not predict how many vectors are extracted from each audio. Therefor I need a structure to hold the vectors dynamically.

Therefor I create a new double array for each vector and push it to a `vector`.

I now want to face and test, if my colleague is really right that the calculation can be boosted with using also an array instead of a vector for storing.

```
vector<double*>* Features = new vector<double*>();
double* feature = new double[12];
// adding elements
Features->push_back(features);
```

As far as i know to create dynamically 2d array I need to know the count of rows.

```
double* container = new double*[rows];
container[0] = new double[12];
// and so on..
```

I know rows after processing all audios, and I don't want to process the audio double times.

Anyone got any idea on how to solve this and append it, or is it just not possible in that way and I should use either `vector` or create own structure (which assumed may be slower than vector).

Comment: I would say before doing anything, it is up to your colleague to back the statement up with numbers, hard facts. I very seriously doubt that using arrays will be faster on optimized code.

Comment: use vectors than arrays. its way better, unless you are working on an embedded system.

Comment: Ahh, three-star programming...

Comment: Consider using vector::reserve with a good approximation of the number of 12-dimensional vectors that you will have in your vector. If you don't then you'll have a lot of reallocations during the setup of your feature. The vector usually starts with a small capacity (see vector::capacity) and every time its internal array gets too small to hold another value, it doubles the size for that array. I.e. it allocates a new array and copies over the values from the old array. That becomes more and more expensive the larger the array is. Thus set the initial capacity big enough so no reallocations

Comment: looking at the code in your question, i think you don't mean 12-dimensional, but array with size 12. a 12 dimensional array would be accessed as v[i0][i1][i2][i3]...[i10][i11]  taking 12 indices.

Comment: 12 dimensional is meant as what it is mathematically. A vector that contains 12 scalars is therefor in R_12 and has 12 dimensions. Therefor to store it I need an array with size 12, as you pointed out. What else you try to say I can't see - maybe you can make it clearer please?

Comment: On the other hand, the increasing cost of copying a large number of values in a growing vector is offset by the copying occurring equally less frequently. Using `reserve` can help though, if you have an idea of what the final size will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless have any strong reasons not to, I would suggest something like this:

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 12>> Features;
```

You get all the memory locality you could want, and all of the the automagic memory management you need.

Comment: You can also pre-allocate in large chunks if that helps with performance.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood it correctly: This will tell the vector to allocate 12 * 4 bytes to ensure that there is proper memory alignment to hold the double array under each position? If that's true, than I guess this would also boost a little :-)

Comment: @Stefan don't worry until your profiler tells you something is unacceptably slow. BTW I would it very hard to find reasons *not* to use this solution.

Comment: @Stefan: The vector manages a dynamic, contiguous array of arrays of twelve doubles. It's hard to see how you could do better than this (unless you have some very specific and unusual access patterns).

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do this, but it would be much better if you perform this with `std::vector`. For dynamic growth of a 2D array, you would have to perform all these things.

- Create a temporary 2D Array
- Allocate memory to it.
- Allocate memory to its each component array.
- Copy data into its component arrays.
- Delete each component array of the original 2D Array.
- Delete the 2D Array.
- Take new Input.
- Add new item to the temporary 2D array.
- Create the original 2D Array and allocate memory to it.
- Allocate memory to its component arrays.
- Copy temporary data into it again.

After doing this in each step, it is hardly acceptable that arrays would be any faster. Use `std:vector`. The above written answers explain that.

Answer (score 0):

Using vector will make the problem easier because it makes growing the data automatic. Unfortunately due to how vectors grow, using vectors may not be the best solution because of the number of times required to grow for a large data set. On the other hand if you set the initial size of the vector quite large but only need a small number of 12 index arrays. You just wasted a large amount of memory. If there is someway to produce a guess of the size required you might use that guess value to dynamically allocate arrays or set the vector to that size initially.

If you are only going to calculate with the data once or twice, than maybe you should consider using map or list. These two structures for large arrays will create a memory structure that matches your exact needs, and bypass the extra time requirements for growing the arrays. On the other hand the calculations with these data structures will be slower.

I hope these thoughts add some alternative solutions to this discussion.